# javascript console letters A and j appeared for Objects, what do they mean

Tags: javascript, extjs, console, console.log

In javascript code, once you use `console.log()` , in the browser console (google chrome), some letters appear before or after an Object description ; letters like *A* and *j*.

[image: google chrome console]
What do these letters mean?

Comment: They are the name of the object

Comment: I think the A would stand for array, not sure on the J though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS (and other js frameworks) uses [private classes](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) to encapsulate objects that are used only internally. They are named sensibly in the source code.

But to improve performance, memory footprint etc., release version of the framework is [minimified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29). As soon as the class or the member is private, you can minimify it's name to single letter. Then a deep inspection of some objects (debugging tools as you're using) may reveal those classes or members with unusual names.

To answer your question, **this is not any console anomaly, those are minimified names** generated when releasing the js framework.