# What does the letters in front of the objects mean in Google Chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, constructor, google-chrome-devtools

There is [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920208/what-does-the-r-mean-in-chrome-dev-tools-when-youre-looking-at-a-backbone-obj) I met while searching what do the letters in front of the objects in Chrome dev tools mean.

In my case I have the `m` letter in front of the `$scope` variable in AngularJS. 
E.g.:

```
vm
m {$id: 1520, $$childTail: m, $$childHead: b, $$prevSibling: m, $$nextSibling: null, …}
```

[image]

So, the linked above question comes to the following conclusion:

> It's the name of the constructor used to create the model object.

That conclusion brings a few questions. I believe they are tightly connected to each other, so I decided to create a single question for all of them.

1. What is the difference between the ordinary JS object and the model object?
2. What is the difference between the ordinary JS object`s constructor and the model object`s constructor?
3. Why did Chrome decided to prepend the letters for the model objects, but decided to avoid doing so for the ordinary JS objects?

**UPDATE**

After the first comment to the question I decided to try the following example:

```
function A() {}
 *undefined*
new A()
 *A {}*
{}
 *{}*
```

[image]

That helped me to understand that the letter prepended to the object is just a name of the constructor. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: 1) What is "ordinary" ? Those that created as literals like `{foo: 123}`? They don't have a constructor function. You or whoever came up with "model" word probably meant a class instance because JS doesn't have `model` objects 2) I guess there's no difference but I'd have to see the actual code and the output of both. 3) Depending on your definition of "ordinary" they just don't have anything to show.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you. I updated my question. Do you think my question is trivial and I should remove it?

Comment: I think that answer is somewhat confusing because it seems to deal with the internals of Backbone. Your question may be answered in more detail by someone who knows the internals of Angular.

Comment: @wOxxOm, ok. Thank you. So, let us see. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that letter is done by the framework when it minifies, what you are probably seeing is their Class or Object in its minified form represented as a letter, basically a wrapper to the object you made.

Comment: oh, i think this person says the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165456/javascript-console-letters-a-and-j-appeared-for-objects-what-do-they-mean

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).